# Создание раскрывающегося меню на JS + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, список

Как настроить раскрывающееся меню на JS при следующих условиях?

У меня есть список ul в котором два li выводятся в цикле (while) из базы данных. Первый li - заголовок (class="nav-header"), второй - элементы меню этого заголовка.

Естественным образом, когда запускается script он автоматически применяется на все li с классом nav-header (открываются и закрываются все li при нажатии на один любой) ибо они выводятся в цикле...

Как привязать какую-либо переменную js чтобы применяемый script действовал на тот li  на который произведено нажатие?

```js
//TOOGLE MENU
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 function close_accordion_section() {
  jQuery('.nav-list .nav-header').removeClass('active');
  jQuery('.nav-list .menu-elements').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
 }

 jQuery('.nav-header').click(function(e) {
  // Grab current anchor value
  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
   close_accordion_section();
  }else {
   close_accordion_section();

   // Add active class to section title
   jQuery(this).addClass('active');
   // Open up the hidden content panel
   jQuery('.nav-list ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
  }

  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `***` WHERE `***`=0 ORDER BY `index`");
while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
 <li class="nav-header" rel="<?=$myrow['***']?>">
  <span><?=$myrow['***']?></span>
<?php 
 if ($data_user['***']==1) 
  { ?>
  <a class="admin_button1" target="_blank" href="/admin/api.php?act=pages&categ_page_id=<?=$myrow['***']?>">
  </a><?php 
  } ?>
 </li>
<?php
$result1=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `***` WHERE ***=".$myrow['***']." AND `***`=0 ORDER BY `index`");
while ($myrow1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
 ?>
 <li categ="<?=$myrow['***']?>" <?php if ($myrow_page['***']==$myrow1['***']) echo 'class="active"'; ?>>
  <a class="menu-elements" href="<?php if (($myrow1['***']==1)||($myrow1['***']==3)) echo '/outpage/'.$myrow1['***']; else echo '/partner/page/'.$myrow1['***']; ?>">
  <?=$myrow1['title']?>
  </a>
 </li>
 <?php
 }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как конкретному элементу давать класс active, предварительно очистите этот класс у остальных li, так как он остается у старых элементов, при этом присваивая и новому

```
$('.nav-header').removeClass('active');
```

Итог

```
$('.nav-header').click(function(e) {        
  e.preventDefault();
  // ----->
  $('.nav-header').removeClass('active');
  //----->
  var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

  if($(this).is('.active')) {
    close_accordion_section();
  }else {
    close_accordion_section();
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('.nav-list ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
  }         
});
```